# How fix the error "ValueError: Julian Day must be positive" in netCDF4.num2date?

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf4

Here is the partial code:

```
import netCDF4
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file='/Users/dedeco/Downloads/_grib2netcdf-atls12-95e2cf679cd58ee9b4db4dd119a05a8d-OzkfHp.nc'
nc = netCDF4.Dataset(file)
nc.variables.keys()

lat = nc.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = nc.variables['longitude'][:]
time_var = nc.variables['time']
dtime = netCDF4.num2date(time_var[:],time_var.units)
```

The file can be download in the link: https://stream.ecmwf.int/data/atls12/data/data01/scratch/84/bc/_grib2netcdf-atls12-95e2cf679cd58ee9b4db4dd119a05a8d-OzkfHp.nc

So, I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-3647c36af24c> in <module>()
      2 lon = nc.variables['longitude'][:]
      3 time_var = nc.variables['time']
----> 4 dtime = netCDF4.num2date(time_var[:],time_var.units)

cftime/_cftime.pyx in cftime._cftime.num2date()

cftime/_cftime.pyx in cftime._cftime.utime.num2date()

cftime/_cftime.pyx in cftime._cftime.DateFromJulianDay()

ValueError: Julian Day must be positive
```

How I can fix? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem set the parameter (the default is standard): **calendar: describes the calendar used in the time calculations.**

So replace this:

```
dtime = netCDF4.num2date(time_var[:],time_var.units)
```

by (in this case the year has 365 days):

```
dtime = netCDF4.num2date(time_var[:],time_var.units,'365_day')
```

[Here is the documentation](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/) as follow:

> def date2num(
>
> ...)
>
> date2num(dates,units,calendar='standard')
>
> Return numeric time values given datetime objects. The units of the
>   numeric time values are described by the units argument and the
>   calendar keyword. The datetime objects must be in UTC with no
>   time-zone offset. If there is a time-zone offset in units, it will be
>   applied to the returned numeric values.
>
> dates: A datetime object or a sequence of datetime objects. The
>   datetime objects should not include a time-zone offset.
>
> units: a string of the form  since 
>   describing the time units.  can be days, hours, minutes,
>   seconds, milliseconds or microseconds.  is the time
>   origin.
>
> calendar: describes the calendar used in the time calculations. All
>   the values currently defined in the CF metadata convention Valid
>   calendars 'standard', 'gregorian', 'proleptic_gregorian' 'noleap',
>   '365_day', '360_day', 'julian', 'all_leap', '366_day'. Default is
>   'standard', which is a mixed Julian/Gregorian calendar.
>
> returns a numeric time value, or an array of numeric time values with
>   approximately millisecond accuracy.

A complementar understand about the conversion can be found [here](https://www.aa.quae.nl/en/reken/juliaansedag.html).